# C++ how to split a string(with NO SPACE or delimiter) into pieces like into an array or vector mini battleship

Tags: c++, arrays, split

I am trying to solve a problem that I have never solved before.
[link](https://open.kattis.com/problems/minibattleship).
I am trying to find the solution to split an input (`cin` to a variable string) and store it in an array or vector.

So if I input: `X..O`
My output would subjectively be like:

```cpp
   s_line[0] = "X";
   s_line[1] = ".";
   s_line[2] = ".";
   s_line[3] = "O";
```

I should also maybe convert this into numbers.

Can any one of you suggest the best solution for this in C++ or does anyone have already solved this? So I can study too how this works.

Comment: What is wrong with `string s; cin>>s; s[3]=='O'`?

Comment: If you read the input `X..O` as a string, it will be put in an array just like you want. Please try to create a [mre] of your attempt, and tell us the *exact* input you get, together with the actual and expected output from the shown example.

Comment: Ohhhhhhhhhh.... Wait I will try that.

Comment: So... do you just want each individual character in a separate string?